# Pick a day in a cycle based on a starting date and the current date

Tags: objective-c, date, cycle

An app allows a user to define an arbitrary set of days like so:

- Day 1 - Pick flowers
- Day 2 - Have coffee
- Day 3 - Go swimming

This set of days may have only one entry or it may have many. Suppose that this cycle of days begins on March 23, 2010.

**Is there a general algorithm that can determine which day in a cycle corresponds to a given calendar day?**

On March 24th, the algorithm should return Day 2, March 25th should be Day 3, March 26th should be Day 1, and so on...

More specifically, I am writing this code for a Cocoa application. So, barring the existence of a more general technique can the Calendar classes help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
NSCalendar *gregorian = ...;
NSDate *startDate = ...;
NSDate *currentDate = [NSDate date];
NSUInteger unitFlags = NSDayCalendarUnit;
NSDateComponents *components = [gregorian components:unitFlags fromDate:startDate  toDate:currentDate options:0];
NSInteger days = [components day];
```

`days` now contains the number of days which have elapsed since the start date. This can be used as an index (zero-based) into your array of activities. You can use the modulus operator with the length of the cycle as the dividend to compute indices after the first transit around the cycle.

Comment: Thank you for providing the Cocoa code for working with the dates, that's very helpful. Once you have `days` you can calculate that mod the number of days in the cycle to get the correct array index.

Comment: Indeed. I have amended my answer to include that fact.

Answer (score 1):

Calculate the [Julian date](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_date) (or a variant) of the start date and the current date (This part is left as an exercise to the reader).  The current day of the cycle is then `(currentDate - startDate) % lengthOfCycle + 1`.

Comment: This is it. Rather simple actually. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

After typing this out I figured out the answer and it is straightforward.

Calculate the number of days between the starting date and the current date then take that number modulo the total number of days in the cycle and you have the current day. Easy peezy.